# Session Management HTML Client and PHP on Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, cordova, session

Serverside: PHP
Clientside: HTML and Javascript

I am trying to create a session manager in HTML (Phonegap). The HTML should maintain the session based on the authentication of PHP on server side.

I am able to start the session in PHP (its in the below code), what i need is, This session code of PHP should start within HTML.

I want the session of PHP in HTML because the phonegap does not understand PHP files. So i need to manage everything with HTML and javascripts.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your ID"   class="inputText"  />

<input type="submit" OnClick="JavaScript:doCallAjax();"  class="inputSubmit" value="Login">
```

**Javascript:**
        Script :
            
                   var HttPRequest = false;

```
               function doCallAjax() {
                  HttPRequest = false;
                  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
                     HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                     if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                        HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
                     }
                  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
                     try {
                        HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                     } catch (e) {
                        try {
                           HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {}
                     }
                  } 

                  if (!HttPRequest) {
                     alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
                     return false;
                  }

                  var url = 'http://localhost:9999/working-DONOT-TOUCH/login.php';
                  var pmeters = "tPassword=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("txt").value );


                    HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);

                    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
                    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
                    HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


                    HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
                    {

                        if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
                        {
                            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Now is Loading...";
                        }

                        if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
                        {
                            if(HttPRequest.responseText == 'Y')
                            {
                                window.location = 'mainmenu.html';

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('Wrong User ID    ');
                            }
                        }

                    }

               }
            </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
    session_start();


    $password = trim($_POST["tPassword"]);




    if(trim($password) == "")
    {
        echo "<font color=red>**</font> Plase enter [ID]";
        exit();
    }


    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','db');



$query = "SELECT * FROM pg_master_students_details WHERE  Stu_Register_No='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if($row)
    {
        echo "Y";


        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
        session_write_close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color=red>**</font> ID is wrong";
    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should manage all html content based on a json requested to your server via javascript.
When you do a login to the server, the server responds by returning a cookie (PHPSESSID).
If you keep using the same cookie on your requests, your session will be the same once logged in. I'm not sure if jquery (for example), maintain the same cookie in each ajax request, but just to keep in mind.